# Trying to add security only for the methods and PUT and DELETE

Tags: spring-boot

I have 3 methods in my Microservice. They are GET,PUT and DELETE. 
I want to security only for PUT and delete methods, there should not be any security for GET method. How I can achieve this.

Please help. Below is the code which allows all the requests.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .httpBasic();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll();
}
```